# Is there any feature to get deploy with changed files only?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am setting up CICD pipeline using git , jenkins and ansible. but I need to deploy those files only which get changed, I don't want to deploy whole context all the time, so which command of ansible i should use for the same?

Comment: Have you looked at the synchronize module? https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/synchronize_module.html#synchronize-module

Comment: Most of the ansible modules are idempotent. And if infact this thing has to be controlled at source. using a combination of webhooks + jenkins the build will be triggered only when there is change. this will ensure that commit only trigger the deployment assuming the commit is actually changing a build package.

Answer (score 0):

In fact what you want to do is the default for Ansible. It is called **Idempotence**.

> [...] the property of certain operations in mathematics and computer science whereby they can be applied multiple times without changing the result beyond the initial application. -- Wikipedia

In your case if you try to copy the same set of files to remote hosts only the files that have changed will be copied. The other files will not be copied.

Hope it helps.

### Example

Here is a simple role copying all the `*.txt` files to a remote host.

```
./roles/file_demo
├── files
│   ├── test.txt
│   └── test2.txt
└── tasks
    └── main.yml
```

```
# main.yaml
---
- name: Copy all text files to /tmp
  copy:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: /tmp/
    owner: root
    mode: 600
  with_fileglob:
    - "*.txt"
```

If I run it two times, the first time files are copied (see `changed` in the stdout below) the second time the files are not copied (see `ok` in the stdout below).

```
$ ansible-playbook -i hosts.ini file_demo.yml                     

PLAY [File module demo] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [file_demo : Copy all text files to /tmp] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [centos] => (item=/home/romain/ansible/roles/file_demo/files/test2.txt)
changed: [centos] => (item=/home/romain/ansible/roles/file_demo/files/test.txt)

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
centos                     : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

$ ansible-playbook -i hosts.ini file_demo.yml

PLAY [File module demo] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [file_demo : Copy all text files to /tmp] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [centos] => (item=/home/romain/ansible/roles/file_demo/files/test2.txt)
ok: [centos] => (item=/home/romain/ansible/roles/file_demo/files/test.txt)

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
centos                     : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```